# How does current split in a circuit?

Tags: current, current-source

I'm redesigning a board that has a lot of peripherals attached to a SOC. These all use different voltages. Board is powered with 12V,1A

Most peripherals are connected like this:

RJ45 <-> GigE phy <-> zynq chip

1) These components all support 3.3V operation. Can I use 1 12V to 3.3V regulator? (If I calculate the current and power needed)

2)If I can, how would I go about doing that?

*Hoping this is easier to understand

Comment: Volt is measure for electric potential, current is measured in ampere. They are not interchangeable terms In fact they are different things completely, albeit tightly connected as described in Ohm's law. Your question don't give clear perspective what you are trying to do. Please explain it better.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, you're way off. You need to add up *all* the loads on each rail (not just the largest) to get the total load.

Comment: @DaveTweed, The current of components in series has to be the same right? So is it in terms of power that I have to add up?

Comment: Also note that simply because a component will work at a given voltage, doesn't mean the component will work within the power dissipation and speed constraints of the design, nor will it necessarily draw the same current. Increasing the core voltage of a processor from 1.25V to 1.8 V will increase current by about 45% and double its power dissipation. The gate capacitances are still the same, but you're charging them to a higher voltage.

Comment: @Relianthe, that's true. But we don't normally hook up components in series between power supply and ground. We usually hook all the loads up in parallel, so each load sees the proper supply voltage.

Comment: Oh of course. Silly me. Messed up the question. Generally there's only one big component, and like a diode or something. I'll just fix it.

Comment: With those kind of power dissipation, using a DC/DC is basically a must. Since you're working with digital, DC/DC will do quite well. In the odd case you need even cleaner voltage noise, using an LDO after the DC/DC ccan help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking but basically:

- If the component says it needs a certain voltage, you need to give it that voltage.
- If it says it's maximum current draw is x Amps, you need a supply that is capable of providing at least this or more. The chip will only pull what it "needs", so it doesn't matter (in 99% of cases - if it does matter, the datasheet will make this clear) whether your supply is capable of providing 1000 times the current required.
- If you have multiple ICs that need different voltages, you need multiple rails - there isn't a way round this. With multiple ICs on one rail, add up their maximum current requirements and make sure your rail can handle more than this. So if all your ICs run at 3.3V, then you can use one 3.3V rail capable of providing the current of all the ICs added together.
- There are situations where even though the ICs run at the same voltage, you may wish to use different rails (of the same voltage) for them. An example is a sensitive analogue circuit on one area of your board, and a high speed digital circuit in another area of your board. It's generally a good idea to use two separate regulators and rails in a case such as this.
- If you are using a linear regulator, make sure you calculate it's power dissipation. For a large voltage difference between IN and OUT combined with a reasonable current draw, it's often a better idea to use a switching regulator.
  For example 12V to 3.3V at 500mA will waste around (12V - 3.3V) * 500mA = 4.35W of power which will be disspated as heat in the regulator. The thermal specifications will tell you how hot the regulator will get without a heatsink. For example, if the junction to ambient (θja) spec is 50°C/W, then the temperature will rise to 4.35 * 50 = 217°C above ambient (so obviously you would need a heatsink in this scenario, most silicon devices have a max operating temperature of ~125°C )

  So in summary, read the datasheet thoroughly for each component, check it's voltage and current requirements and tolerances (i.e. how much it can be over or under the nominal value) and make sure your rails are capable of meeting the specs. There will often be advice on layout and a basic circuit shown in the datasheet.